# Offline Access in PHP SDK w/ a valid accesstoken

Tags: php, facebook

i asked a last time about offline access in PHP, and i was told that as long as i have a valid accessToken from a user, and if i have offline_access permission i can interact with the user WHILE he is logged out of facebook.

but to be honest i have NO idea why its failing on me.

first: i have offline_access and the users accessToken. i want to save the accessToken to a secure DB, and then when calling facebook PHP API, i want to be able to supply the accessToken and allow the user to interact with facebook as if the user was signed in to facebook.

i tried to manually set the accessToken and userid (both which is saved when a user allows access to the app). the getting of data works (i.e the user can a view their stream/pics etc. but they cannot post statuses (which they can if they are logged in).

does the permissions allow that? or no

Answer (score 0):

To publish statuses you still need the [`publish_stream` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: You don't need the access token once you have the `publish_stream` permission all you need is the user id.

Comment: sorry if its being dumb...but is this even after they are offline?? because im getting the error:
Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist LINE: base_facebook.php on line 1036

line details: 
`$e = new FacebookApiException($result);`
here is what im doing to post the status_stream:
`$attachment = array('message' => $string);


    $result = $this->facebook->api($this->uid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);`